# Passing values from one page to another page in JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one query on JavaScript.

How we can pass values from one page to another page?

I am working with ASP.NET. My requirement is, I need to validate the user, whether his session expired or not. If the session expired then I need to show a pop up with two textboxes to enter his credentials.

In which case I was unable to do that in ASP.NET. So though of doing with the help of JS. But not getting ideas.

I know we can pass values from one page to another using querystring. But as per the security purpose that is not to be used in my app.

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that on the javascript side. Remember that you **can't** trust the client side.

Use ASP.NET to do this.

See this tutorial to get some help about using sessions: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Managing-Sessions.aspx

Comment: But my case is, if my session expired... then I should not navigate the user to another page, as the user will lose his/her data, which they have entered in that page. Hope I am clear.

Comment: And what is the problem? That looks like a simple `if` case.

Comment: If the session expired, then what should I do? Should I show a pop up? or should I navigate the user to login page?

Comment: That is your business logic, I have no idea what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the users info in a session, for example his id and current request time. Then you can compare the previous request time, which you saved while processing the previous request, with the current time. You save the current request time in the session again. If it's been to long ago you show him the login popup. If you need a more secure way of passing the login credentials I recommend using a ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookies. That's also not really secure, but it's obviously a lot more secure than query strings, though if you're dealing with something that requires more security than what cookies offer, then I would suggest that you're doing something really wrong. (Welcome to Stack)

Comment: Yeah... Dredel, I can use cookies. But as you said, that is not secure. Even I can easily track that from my browsers like Chrome or Mozilla.. Can I try something else in JS. I am not very much familiar with JS..

Comment: The question is, what *sort of security are you looking for? What are you worried about? Cookies are domain restricted, so, your cookies can't be read by some other website.  Are you concerned that someone who isn't the user might crack open the browser's cookie file and start rooting around in it? I mean... what sort of data are you storing?!

Comment: The data what I am storing is client specific. The client will fire me if they come to know that somebody can track this from outside. And that is more critical. Thats what I am worried.

Comment: that's what I'm asking... what do you mean "outside"? Outside what? Outside the cubicle? Outside the bedroom? A cookie file resides on the user's computer. Again, I ask you what kind of data are you storing? Is it the authorization key you hand them when they log in? Cause that's perfectly safe to store in a cookie, it's how google and amazon do it, as well as banks.

Comment: I will go for AJAX modal pop up extender, which is more secured. I got to know, we cannot use JS, which is not more secured. Thanks for your help.